# Proxy within IIS - win10

Tags: iis, proxy

This would be my scenario:

- device sends HTTP request (GET) to IIS hosted on Win10 machine (same internal network)
- IIS routes the HTTP request to a different website on the Internet that uses HTTPS

How would I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The search term you are looking for is `reverse proxy`.

Comment: Hi and thank you Gerald, I managed to make it work by creating a dummy website and adding an inbound rule, simple pattern .* and it just rewrites to the HTTPS external website.

I think my only problem would be the dummy website bindings. 
I have two of them, one for 80 and one for 443 with a proper certificate added.
The whole thing works just fine when I access the dummy website from the machine that's hosting the configured IIS, when I do it from another machine in the same network (I'm using IP as opposed to localhost) it just returns a 404.

Am I missing something here?